# Nested Serializer for Many to Many

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Python and Django. I am creating api using Django-Rest-Framework I want to serializer data that can accept json in below format:

```
{
"ingredients": ["Sugar","Egg"],
"name": "Cake",
"description": "Dinner Food",
"directions": "direction1"
}
```

However I am able to persist data in db with below format:

```
{
"ingredients": [{"name":"Cake"},{"name":"Egg"}],
"name": "Rice",
"description": "Dinner Food",
"directions": "direction1"
}
```

I am not sure how can I convert dictionary in to the set field. I am aware of [List field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) and [list serialiser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) but not sure how to use them.
Is it possible to do this using model serialiser?

Serializer.py

```
class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = '__all__'


class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Recipe
            fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        print(ingredients_data)
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient in ingredients_data:
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient['name'])
            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
        return recipe
```

Model.py

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    directions = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view.py

```
class RecipieView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeSerializer


class IngredientView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ingredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = IngredientSerializer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use two different serializers for creation purpose and others. See the below snippet,
**views.py**

```
class RecipieView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeMainSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return RecipeCreateSerializer
        return RecipeMainSerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class RecipeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient in ingredients_data:
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient)
            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
        return recipe


class RecipeMainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can redirect me to some resource to make me understand exactly the flow cycle and would it be possible to post a file that has the json data to stream and ingest into database. I think parsing a file and sending multiple post request would not be ideal solution

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestions on this, but why exactly would you suggest two different Serializers?

Comment: As the OP mention, you need different behavior on your HTTP GET method as well as in your HTTP POST method. You could override few methods in the serializer so that you can avoid the use of *multiple* serializer. Hope it's here :) @math

Answer (score 0):

We can refactor @JPG serializers in better way like this:

```
class RecipeMainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = '__all__'

class RecipeCreateSerializer(RecipeMainSerializer):
    ingredients = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredients_data = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient in ingredients_data:
            ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient)
            recipe.ingredients.add(ingredient)
        return recipe
```

This improve [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle of our codes in more complicated serializers