# How to update the serializer field for m2m relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update submitted data by implementing the update() method on the a SerializerClass. However i do not know how to get access to the current ingredient of the current instance and also i do not know how to iterate through the validated data such that i can assign the key and values correctly. any advice would be appreciated!

**My Serializer**

```
class RecipeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
    owner = ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        fields = ['owner', 'name', 'description', 'image', 'ingredients']
        model = Recipe

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredient_datas = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient_data in ingredient_datas:
            recipe.ingredients.create(**ingredient_data)
        return recipe

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)

        for ingredient in validated_data.get('ingredients'):
            for key, value in ingredient.items():
                print(key, value)
                instance.ingredient.name = value
                instance.ingredient.amount = value
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

**My Models**

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='recipes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='recipes')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Some window shell ouputs

print(validated_data)

```
{'name': 'bedddef', 'description': 'gdddoot', 'image': 'httpdddlo', 'ingredients': [OrderedDict([('name', 'tomatoes'), ('amount', 2)]), OrderedDict([('name', 'bread'), ('amount', 3)])]}
```

for key, value in ingredient.items():
    print(key, value)

```
name tomatoes
amount 2
name bread
amount 3
```

Recently (today)
I recreated the entire api again because i lost it. I tried using the same code bear suggested for the update() method using Ingredient.objects.get_or_create() but i got an error saying.

MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/recipes/3/
get() returned more than one Ingredient -- it returned 2!

Because of the error i substituted get_or_create() for just create() would that be a bad solution?

```
   def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.descriptions = validated_data.get('descriptions', instance.descriptions)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        ingredients = []
        for ingredient in validated_data.get('ingredients'):
            obj = Ingredient.objects.create(**ingredient)
            ingredients.append(obj)
        print(ingredients)
        instance.ingredients.set(ingredients)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: is it your question [serializer-for-many-to-many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625057/nested-serializer-for-many-to-many/50625290#50625290)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`set`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) method of the m2m RelatedManager

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
    instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
    instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
    ingredients = []
    for ingredient in validated_data.get('ingredients'):
        obj, _ = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(**ingredient)
        ingredients.append(obj)
    instance.ingredients.set(ingredients)
    #                 ^^^^^^
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

details: the `get_or_create` return tuple of the model instance and bool value is created new instance, but we don't need the bool, so to do the code more readable just assign the value of the variable `_`

```
obj, _ = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(**ingredient)
```

Comment: omg thanks bear it worked! it should be ingredients.append(obj) though. 
couple of questions.. 
(1)What is the _ after obj for? 
(2) how can i get as good as you ?

Comment: for 1. question i edit the answer, for 2. no magic: learn python in the online course, read django documentation, read the code of the projects in the github